# --disableChecks not working in Protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I'm trying to use the new `--disableChecks` option in Protractor
So, this command works

```
$> ./node_modules/./bin/protractor protractor-conf.js
```

But this one doesn't:

```
$> ./node_modules/./bin/protractor protractor-conf.js --disableChecks
[14:42:47] E/configParser - Error code: 105
[14:42:47] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file ./tests/protractor.conf.js
[14:42:47] E/configParser - UNKNOWN_OPTION: Unknown option: --disableChecks
```

Below is the protractor code in which this is happening `./node_modules/protractor/build/configParser.js`:

```
 /**
 * Public function specialized towards merging in a file's config
 *
 * @public
 * @param {String} filename
 */
addFileConfig(filename) {
    if (!filename) {
        return this;
    }
    let filePath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), filename);
    let fileConfig;
    try {
        fileConfig = require(filePath).config;
    }
    catch (e) {
        throw new exitCodes_1.ConfigError(logger, 'failed loading configuration file ' + filename, e);
    }
    if (!fileConfig) {
        throw new exitCodes_1.ConfigError(logger, 'configuration file ' + filename + ' did not export a config object');
    }
    fileConfig.configDir = path.dirname(filePath);
    this.addConfig_(fileConfig, fileConfig.configDir);
    return this;
}
```

it is the `require(filePath)` which fails, but in both cases the `filePath`s are identical.

Any help would be appreciated

Node version: 7.2.1, Protractor version: 5.0.0

Comment: Shot in the dark: what if you install the latest node and npm and clean the cache with `sudo npm cache clean -f`?

Comment: Is there an option named - `disablechecks` in protractor? never heard of it

Comment: Yes, if you do `--help` you will see it. Anyway,  I've updated node to version `7.4.0`, which now gives me npm version `4.0.5`. For the installation of modules I'm using yarn, which has version `0.17.10`. But I still get the exact same error :(

Comment: Why is that, if I do `./node_modules/.bin/protractor --help` the last arguments in the list is:  ` --disableChecks     disable cli checks`

Comment: I am using Protractor 4.0.10 and on `protractor --help` .. I dont see it :( what is the version of Protractor you are using and can you update the question with the output of the command please

Comment: You'll need [5.0.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500)

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, protractor works perfect, it was something in my protractor.conf